# How to login using SSO oauth 2.0 and then storing token to run all other API from postman automation script?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, automated-tests, single-sign-on, postman-pre-request-script

I am not able to automate postman script for this procedure:

1. Open postman then in authorization tab select type->OAuth 2.0, Add authorization data->Request Headers and Access token->Get Access Token
   Filled fields-Token Name, Grant Type->Authorization Code, Callback URL, Auth Url, Acess Token Url, client Id, Scope, State, Client Authentication->Send as basic Auth header
   then when request Token a pop up window opens for SSO
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUPjg.jpg)
2. Then Manage Acess tokens pop up appears, then select Use Token button at the bottom, then running api url which now contain token in the Header tab->temperory headers.
   How to automate this procedure with storing token in environment variables,then running rest of the API's with it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access access_token from oauth 2.0 login by using Express and puppeteer.

```
var express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    run().then(() => console.log('Done')).catch(error => console.log(error));
    async function run(){
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://abcd.com/authorize? 
audience=https://abcd.com&scope=openid%20email%20profile&client_id=abcd&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://abcd.com/callback');
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    await page.focus('#email');
    await page.keyboard.type('abcd@gmail.com');
    await page.focus('#password');
    await page.keyboard.type('efghi');
    const waitForLoad = new Promise(resolve => page.on('load', () => resolve()));
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.querySelector('span[class="label"]').click();
    });
    await waitForLoad;
    console.log('Waiting to be redirected to the client.');
    const clientUrl = await page.evaluate(() => window.location.href);
        //1st the split is from when it encounters = in the url
    var split1 = clientUrl.split('=');
    //2nd split is when it encounters & in the 2nd object of the array
    var split2 = split1[1].split('&');
    //taking array in an object and conversing it to json
    var obj = {
      access_token: split2[0]
    }
    await browser.close();
    res.send(obj);
  };
});
app.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log('Heard on 8000');
});
```

This can be run on postman to run other api with the received access token.

Answer (score 0):

Using refresh token This can also be achieved in less time
Get refresh token by API https://{{auth0_domain}}/oauth/token
BODY-

```
grant_type:password      
client_id:abcdefghijklmn
audience:https://abcd.com
username:abcd
password:efgh
scope:openid profile email offline_access
```

In Response will generate Refresh Token, this token then can be used in getting accesss_token without again generating refresh token in future. It's a one time process only and it doesn't get expired in a day or a week or a month.